# How did Rey repair the Skywalker lightsaber?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, the-rise-of-skywalker

In *The Last Jedi* Rey and Kylo have a tug of war over the old Skywalker lightsaber, was Anakin's, then Luke's (who lost it), then Maz gave it Rey etc.

However, in *The Rise of Skywalker* the lightsaber is suddenly rebuilt and working again with no explanation. As far as I know building lightsaber's is a tough thing to do and one of the final tests for a youngling. And the lightsaber split the kyber crystal in two so it wasn't as simple to just glue the two sides back together again.

How did Rey fix the broken Skywalker lightsaber?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBza2.png

Comment: +1 for the title, I don't understand why people get into arguments about if it's Anakin's Luke's or Rey's. The way I see it is that if it's in your possession and the previous owners are dead with no heir then it's technically yours (thus Rey's). But I don't even care.

Comment: @DJSpicyDeluxe I don't really care, I just called it the Skywalker lightsaber to avoid the semantics of it all. When looking for the answer though it turns out it is called the Skywalker lightsaber in The Visual Dictionary as well.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Yeah, the +1 is for the neutrality.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot:   Well, she's a Skywalker anyways, right?   Right?  Lalala. Nothing to see here?!

Comment: @ThePopMachine : You meant Mary Sue, right?

Comment: She can fly ships better than most without prior experience; she can swim better than most even though she lived on a desert planet; she can bypass the compressor on Han Solo's ship even though she spent her life scavenging and breaking things apart to sell for scraps; she learnt Jedi skills and bested Kylo with barely any training; oh and she can force heal and resurrect people from the dead. So yah, she can fix a little light saber with no problemo...

Comment: Apparently The Empire had struck down the (Apple Corp, John Deere) DRM lock-in to allow independent repair shops to work on light sabres.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I've spent a bit of time looking around and found the followng. In *The Rise of Skywalker: The Visual Dictionary* the lightsaber has several annotations on it reading:

> Leather wrist strap repurposed to bind broken shaft
>
> Weld marks
>
> Kyber crystal inside healed using techniques gleaned from Jedi scripture

[image: The Skywalker Lightsaber annotated from The Visual Dictionary quoted above]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

Of course fixing the casing was the easy bit for Rey from being a scavenger, she just welded it back together and used some leather strapping to help bind the two halves together. However, it also seems from the Jedi scripture she took from Ahch-To was some information on healing the Kyber crystal.

We get a bit more information on this later on in *The Visual Dictionary* where is states the following along with an image of Rey's little workstation on Ajan Kloss:

> Rey is fascinated by the arcane healing techniques described in the *Chronicles of Brus-bu*, and uses the underpinnings of such teachings to heal the broken kyber crystal in her lightsaber.

This is of note because it would seem that she actually taught herself how to do it somewhat from some related teachings but not teachings on how to do it specifically. We also see some *"Lightsaber diagrams"* in one of the books so it's likely there was a bit more information on how lightsabers worked in them even if not down to the detail of bonding a kyber crystal.

[image: Lightsaber drawings in some of the Jedi scripture shown in The Visual Dictionary]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

Lastly, I think it is worth noting that in *The Rise of Skywalker* we learn that Leia underwent Jedi training and even constructed her own lightsaber that Rey uses later on. Whilst we never see Leia teaching Rey on constructing a lightsaber, that I know of, she was training her. It's possible that as part of this training Leia also helped Rey with repairing the old Skywalker lightsaber.

Comment: There's more infor from novelization